# Providing a long answer

Tags: discussion

I would like to answer at length a certain question posted on math.stackexchange.com. My answer, if printed, would comprise several A4 pages. Is there a certain size limit for an answer? Is there a more convenient way to post an answer (more convenient for editing, for cross-referencing within the answer, quicker to render)?

Comment: [related](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-posts)

Comment: See also: [The upper limit on the size of an answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23346/the-upper-limit-on-the-size-of-an-answer).

Comment: You might enjoy [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/516639/longest-answer) that tells you the longest answers on this site. You can see how other people dealt with their desire to write long posts. (Though ignore the longest answer. It's not particularly stunning in composition)